# Spring RestController Mapping method has object with null fields when making request with valid JSON body

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, httprequest

I am trying to test my `@PostMapping` in on of my `@RestController`.
That controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyTestController
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @PostMapping(path = "/foo")
    public String add(@Valid Boo boo, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        if (LoadManager.insert(request.getRemoteAddr()) < 3)
            try
            {
                BooManager.persist(boo);
                return "1";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        return "0";
    }
}
```

However `boo` fields are all null when I make a post request and look at boo object during debug in that add method.

Request body:

```
{
    "officialName" : "test",
    "phone" : "test",
    "email" : "test",
    "churchArea" : "test",
    "deanery" : "test",
    "town" : "test",
    "pass" : "test152S56"
}
```

Request header `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`

Boo class:

```
@Data
public class Boo
{
    @Size(max = 1000)
    @NotBlank
    private String officialName;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotBlank
    private String phone;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotBlank
    private String churchArea;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotBlank
    private String deanery;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotBlank
    private String town;

    @Size(max = 1000)
    @NotBlank
    private String pass;
}
```

@Data annotation is from [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data), which generates, among other things, public getters and setter for that class.

Comment: Can you post your `@GetMapping` method?

Comment: private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(); remove static from it

Comment: Your method param Boo is missing @RequestBody

Comment: @Sar Why should I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to bound a request body to method parameter you should use @RequestBody annotation. That's why your Boo object attributes are null.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/foo")
public String add(@RequestBody Boo boo, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html